# Как в Javascript ссылаться из одного index.js в другой файл работая с дочерними webpack / bable?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel, webpack5

День добрый, всем. Подскажите как ссылаться из одного `index.js` файла, на другой `index.js` файл работая в дочерних `package` / `webpack5` ?

```
root
  |dist
  |
  |src
  |  |backend
     |  |src
     |     |serve
     |     |    |index.ts
     |     |
     |     |index.js
     |
     |db
     | |src
     |    |db
     |    |  |index.ts
     |    |index.js
     |
     |frontend
     | |src
     |   |img
     |   |scss
     |   |ts
     |   |  |index.ts
     |   |  |functions
     |   |  |modules
     |   |  |main.ts
     |   |index.js
     |
     |index.js
```

Какие условия соблюдать, чтоб из `src/backend/scr/serve/index.js` ,
используя const `const db = require()`
сослаться на `src/db/src/db/index.js` ? При этом условие, что в папке `dist` из одного файла ссылка, в другой остается рабочей

```js
// шапка scr/serve/index.js
 const http = require('http'), Koa = require('koa'), json = require('koa-json'); 
....
const db = require('../../db/src/db/index.js');
....
```

Уже в webpack используя `resolve.alias` для ссылки создаю имя

```js
// webpack

db: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../db/src')
```

и тогда эта строка

```js
// scr/serve/index.js
const db = require('../db/src/serve');
```

работает (на стороне `src`) через

```js
// scr/serve/index.js

const db = require('db/index.js');
```

Но на стороне `dist`, после `webpack / babel` 2 файла  сливаются (как и сливались) в один (как понимаю) , в тот где и был

```js
// src/serve/index.js
const db = require();
```

В итоге получаю ошибку, так как эта строка

```js
// dist/serve/index.js

const db = require();
```

становится не рабочей, ему сослаться некуда когда оказывается на стороне  `dist`.

Что происходит c  `resolve.alias`, после  `webpack / babel`

```js
// webpack

db: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../db/src')
```

вообще не понимаю (не знаю)
Ни где ответ не могу найти

1. Какие условия соблюдать, чтоб из `src/backend/scr/serve/index.js` ,
   используя const `const db = require()`
   сослаться на `src/db/src/db/index.js` ? При этом условие, что в папке `dist` из одного файла ссылка, в другой остается рабочей
2. Что происходит c  `resolve.alias`, после  `webpack / babel`?

Comment: Для начала вопрос зачем нужно собрать вебпаком код для бекенда?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, на данный момент не могу ответить на данный вопрос т.к. еще и года нет как config-ами овладел. 

"db" (заглушка) и "serve " файлы разделены (не зависимо от локации  "db" ).

При сборке могу получить 2-а варианта. 1) с наличием отдельного файла  "db"  и 2)  без отдельного. 
В обоих вариантах ДО сборки в "serve" есть import  "db" . + ПОСЛЕ сборки (в "dist"-шную папку) в  "serve"-ном файле получаю код из  "db"-ного файла.

Comment: @AlexeyTen,  Нацелив запуск от/из "dist" получаю ошибку из "serve" . Ссылка  import остается в "serve"  и не рабочая. + код из  "db"  файла в "serve" 

Мне надо понять/увидеть (код) как разделять файлы  "serve"  и   "db"  иначе в будущем Если все сливать в один файл, то его вес  может не позволить вместить весь проект.
Цель кода - научиться пользоваться `Koa()` и `WebSocket`

`собрать вебпаком код для бекенда` Какая есть альтернатива?